# java.lang.NullPointerException at Cucumber

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am getting the below exception,Please check if could help me on it.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.cucumber.framework.stepdefinition.PersonalInfo.Personal_InfoSD.enter_the_EmpID(Personal_InfoSD.java:30)
```

Code:

```
package com.cucumber.framework.stepdefinition.PersonalInfo;

import com.cucumber.framework.PageObject.AddEmployeeForm;
import com.cucumber.framework.PageObject.Personal_InfoPage;
import com.cucumber.framework.configreader.ObjectRepo;
import com.cucumber.framework.helper.TestBase.TestBase;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class Personal_InfoSD {
    Personal_InfoPage personalinfo;
    AddEmployeeForm AddEmployee;

    @Given("^navigate to application$")
    public void navigate_to_application() throws Throwable {
        TestBase.driver.get(ObjectRepo.reader.getWebsite());
    }

    @When("^user clicks on the Add employee button$")
    public void user_clicks_on_the_Add_employee_button() throws Throwable {
        AddEmployeeForm AddEmployee = new AddEmployeeForm(TestBase.driver);
        AddEmployee.Click_Add_Emp_Button();
    }


    @When("^enter the EmpID \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void enter_the_EmpID(String arg1) throws Throwable {
        personalinfo.EnterEmpID(arg1);
    }

}
```

Sorry if i have made any mistake in asking question,I am new to cucumber tool kindly help me

Comment: personalinfo is null. Where are u initializing it?

Comment: Thank you it was already solved.